# Attempt execution uniquness in a java project?

Tags: java

I am working a java library, which has a singleton class with a methods - `createTask()` and `addPointsToTask()`

The library is meant to be used in any java service which executes multiple requests.

The service should be able to call `createTask` **only once** during it's processing of a single request. Any further calls to `createTask` in the same thread execution should fail. `addPointsToTask` can be called any number of times.

As a library owner how can I restrict this method to be called only once per thread?

I have explored [ThreadLocal](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/threadlocal.html), but don't think it fits my purpose.

One solution is to ask the service that is using the library to set a unique id in threadLocal, but as this 'set-to-thread-local' solution is outside the boundary of the library, this is not a full-proof solution.

Any hints?

Comment: Many things reuse threads, so if you're trying to limit usage on a per-thread basis, it can result in weird things. For example servlet containers have a (small) set of working threads to handle the requests, this would mean that only the first requests on a specific thread would succeed.

Comment: You could maybe look at ```currentThread()``` and store that id and in the method call check if ```currentThread()``` was not already used

Comment: I doubt you can create a programmatic solution for this. The user can always start new threads to execute those calls, and your library wouldn't know it. Why do you have such requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to prohibit multiple calls from the same request, simply because your library has no concept of what a "request" actually is. This very much depends on the service using the library. Some services may use a single thread per request, but others may not. Using thread-locals is error-prone especially when you are working in multi-threaded or reactive applications where code processing a request can execute on multiple parallel threads.

If your requirement is that `addPointsToTask` is only called for a task that was actually started by some code that is processing the current request, you could set up your API like that. E.g. `createTask` could return a context object that is required to call `addPointsToTask` later.

```java
public TaskContext createTask() {
}

public void addPointsToTask(TaskContext context, ....) {
}
```

This way you can track task context even over multiple different threads executing code for the same request and points will not get added to a task created by another request.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: you won't get a "fool-proof" solution; i.e. a solution that someone can't subvert.

Unless you are running your library on a JVM platfrom that you control, users of your library will be able to find a way to subvert your "only once per thread" restriction if they try hard enough.  For example:

- They could use reflection to access the private state of the objects or classes that implement the restriction.
- They could use bytecode injection to subvert your code.
- They could decompile and replacing your code.
- They could modify their JVM to do something funky with your code.  (The OpenJDK source code is available to anyone.)

Ask yourself the following:

- Is this restriction reasonable from the perspective of the programmer you are trying to restrict?
- Would a sensible programmer have good reason to try to break it?
- Have you considered possible use-cases for your library where it would be reasonable to call `createTask()` multiple times?  For example, use-cases that involve using thread pools?

If you are doing this because you think allowing multiple `createTask()` calls will break your library, my advice would be:

- Tell the programmer via the javadocs and other documentation what is likely to break if they do the thing that you are trying to prevent.
- Implement a "soft" check, and provide an easy way for a programmer to disable the check.   (But do the check by default, if you think that is appropriate.)

The point is that a sensible programmer won't knowingly subvert restrictions unless they have good reason to.  If they do, and they hurt themselves, that is not your problem.

On the other hand, you are implementing this restriction for "business reasons" or to stop "cheating" or something like that, my advice would be to recognize that a determined user will be able to subvert *any* restrictions you attempt to embed in your code when they run it on their platform.  If this fundamentally breaks your model, look for a different model.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method to your singleton which runs some piece of Service-Code in the context of a request.

Dummy implementation:

```java
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public enum YourLibrarySingleton {

    INSTANCE;

    private final ThreadLocal<Task> threadLocalTask;

    YourLibrarySingleton() {
        this.threadLocalTask = new ThreadLocal<>();
    }

    public void createTask() {
        this.threadLocalTask.set(new Task() {});
    }

    public void addPointsToTask() {
        Task task = this.threadLocalTask.get();
        // add points to that task
    }

    public <T> T handleRequest(Callable<T> callable) throws Exception {
        try {
            return callable.call();
        } finally {
            this.threadLocalTask.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```java
package stackoverflow;

public class ServiceCode {

    public void handleRequest() throws Exception {
        YourLibrarySingleton.INSTANCE.handleRequest(() -> {
            YourLibrarySingleton.INSTANCE.createTask();
            YourLibrarySingleton.INSTANCE.addPointsToTask();
            YourLibrarySingleton.INSTANCE.addPointsToTask();

            return "result";
        });
    }
}
```